# Can't get any release to start?

Tags: erlang, centos, rabbitmq, rebar

So, I thought I'd create a bonafide release to run my next application in. Unfortunately, there seems to be a deal breaker.

First I tried making a project from scratch using this guide:

http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html

That failed with an obscure error, so just to make sure, I tried to run a project I know is good, etorrent.

When I tried to run etorrent's release, I got the same error:

```
[me@my-ip etorrent]# rel/etorrent/bin/etorrent console
Exec: /root/etorrent/rel/etorrent/erts-5.8.4/bin/erlexec -boot /root/etorrent/rel/etorrent/releases/1.2.1/etorrent -embedded -config /root/etorrent/rel/etorrent/etc/app.config -args_file /root/etorrent/rel/etorrent/etc/vm.args -- console
Root: /root/etorrent/rel/etorrent
pthread/ethr_event.c:98: Fatal error in wait__(): Function not implemented (38)
Aborted
```

I searched for that error, and the serps are filled with references to RabbitMQ on CentOS having the same problem. Obviously, it's more general than a RabbitMQ problem specifically. Based on this thread:

[RabbitMQ install issue on Centos 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463503/rabbitmq-install-issue-on-centos-5-5)

...and my own experience, it seems like running releases on 14 series erlang installations coupled with series 5 CentOS doesn't work. I installed the latest erlang up on the site last night, by the way, so that's what I'm using. I didn't pass any flags to 'configure', just used the stock options.

Does anyone have any idea if there's a compile option for erlang that might fix this? Or any other advice? Is anyone else successfully using rebar created releases for applications in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem that needed to be solved on the CentOS side if you look at this comment to this [RabbitMQ install issue on Centos 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463503/rabbitmq-install-issue-on-centos-5-5/5465889#5465889) answer

> Compilation of Erlang R14B03 (erts-5.8.4) works on CentOS 5.6 (Final)
>   VirtualBox VM

So it looks to me that you need to upgrade your CentOS to 5.6