# Failed to install rabbitmq-server on Linux(Oracle Linux Server release 6.7/RHEL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, installation, rabbitmq, rhel

I am getting following error while installing.

```
$ sudo yum install rabbitmq-server
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, fastestmirror, kabi, presto, refresh-packagekit, security, tmprepo, ulninfo, verify, versionlock
Loading support for kernel ABI
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * ol6_UEKR3: slcac475.us.oracle.com
 * ol6_latest: slcac475.us.oracle.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.1.5-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution`
...
...
...
groupadd: Can't get unique system GID (no more available GIDs)
useradd: group 'rabbitmq' does not exist 
error: %pre(rabbitmq-server-3.1.5-1.el6.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 6
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package rabbitmq-server-3.1.5-1.el6.noarch
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping rabbitmq-server-3.1.5-1.el6
Verifying  :
 rabbitmq-server-3.1.5-1.el6.noarch

Failed 
rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.1.5-1.el6
Complete!
```

Note: I have already installed the `erlang`

I have refereed few posts already there

[Installing rabbitmq-server on RHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855331/installing-rabbitmq-server-on-rhel)

[RabbitMQ install issue on Centos 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463503/rabbitmq-install-issue-on-centos-5-5/9301512#9301512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `/etc/login.defs` and check if you have something like this, if not add it into it.

```
SYS_GID_MIN               2000
SYS_GID_MAX               9000
```